# Built in Sprite Kit level designer in Xcode 6

Tags: sprite-kit, ios8, xcode6

I found this hint in the Xcode 6 beta documentation:

'Support for Sprite Kit has been significantly enhanced with a new Sprite Kit level designer, ...'

Does anybody know, where I can find it?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Xcode 6 is under NDA.

Comment: Apple has changed their NDA terms: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/

Comment: interesting but IANAL .. no idea whether it means we can talk about it all in detail including things that we only learned from documentation and using the prerelease software and services, or whether we can only talk about things that were in the wwdc sessions and no more. I would tend to the latter if only to be on the safe side, but it makes it even harder not to violate nda terms because who can actually remember for sure what was in which session?

Comment: I understand the problem. Actually this NDA is at least an improvement to last years NDA. But I don't think we can cancel all iOS8, XCode6 and Swift tagged questions...

Comment: Swift docs are public, so that's definitely in the clear and you'll find lots of swift questions on so already. As for this question, it says the quoted text is in the prerelease docs, so i tend to say 'nay'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it. Just create a new project with the 'Game' template. This template creates automatically an sks (Sprite Kit Scene) file. In the scene you can drag your sprites, define bounding boxes, physics, ...

Update: Ray Wenderlich has created an excellent [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor)

Comment: You can see this in action in the 'Platform State of the Union' video from the WWDC 2014 (minute 40)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create sprites in the level editor, but I find no information how to used them programmatically once they appear on the scene.